# completeness in $C^\infty [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Good day, how show that $C^\infty [a,b]=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty C^k[a,b]$ is complete with norm 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\frac{\| f^{(n)}-g^{(n)}\|_\infty}{1+\| f^{(n)}-g^{(n)}\|_\infty} \text{?}$$

Thanks.

Comment: Btw, that's not a "norm", but only a "metric". The key point resides in showing that each $C^k$ is a Banach space, which has the key point of showing that if $f_n$ is a $C^1$-Cauchy sequence of $C^1$ functions, that the derivative of the limit is the limit of the derivatives... which follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus.